# XCTest sleep() function?

Tags: xcode, swift, xctest

I am testing an app which samples data. Part of the test I am setting up requires a few data points to be stored. I would like to do this by having XCTest execute the acquisition method followed by a sleep() function and yet another call to the acquisition method.

Though there are methods to wait for an expectation with timeout, there doesn't seem to be a simple wait()/sleep() method that simply pauses execution for specified amount of time.  Any idea how I can do this using Xcode 6 and Swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `NSTimer` to space out your data calls instead of locking up the app with `sleep`

```
func dataCall(timer : NSTimer) {

   // get data
}
let myTimer : NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: Selector("dataCall:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

and of course you can alter those parameters to your liking and needs.

Comment: ah yes, of course. that will work just fine, thanks.